# Should you always use the jQuery first() method when you know there will only be one matching element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

When you are attempting to select an element in jQuery and you know there will only be one element, is it still beneficial to use the `first()` method for performance reasons or is it better to *not* use it?

For example:

```
$('#myForm').children('input[name=some_field]');
```

VS:

```
$('#myElement').children('input[name=some_field]').first();
```

Comment: If you are sure then no need to bother, I think.

Comment: If there is only one element, .first() does nothing (other than pointlessly call a function)

Comment: The functions are executed in order. If you add `.first` you're adding another function. Why would that increase performance?

Comment: @Stryner Oh ok, thanks. I thought it may halt it searching for anymore elements once it finds the first one; but I guess even if there *were* more it would still find them all but only return the first?

Comment: @Brett Exactly. If you did `input[name=some_field]:first` it might improve performance, but even that's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:first` selector would probably be better at **short-circuiting** the search

```
$('#myElement').children('input[name=some_field]:first')
```

Answer (score 2):

no, is not "beneficial"... the `first()` method only apply for an DOM array elements.

https://api.jquery.com/first/

Answer (score 0):

In that case use `.length` in jquery

```
if($('#myForm').children('input[name=some_field]').length)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one of them and you know the id, use the id. Otherwise for your inputs,

```
// Get the value from a dropdown select

$( "select.foo option:selected").val();

// Get the value from a dropdown select even easier
$( "select.foo" ).val();

// Get the value from a checked checkbox

$( "input:checkbox:checked" ).val();

// Get the value from a set of radio buttons

$( "input:radio[name=bar]:checked" ).val();
```

Even if you do not want the values, it is a way for you to access those elements. Just couple of examples of accessing it directly instead of going from the parent element.